# Return List of Latest .tar Files as found in File Name Python

Tags: python

I have various tar files in a folder "supertar", labeled as:-

```
esarchive--Mona-AB-Test226-8037affd-06d1-4c61-a91f-816ec9cb825f-05222017-4.tar,
esarchive--Jackson-HQ-112-ecb5ab6a-c199-402d-9a8a-8c54c8901d66-06092017-4.tar,
esarchive--Mona-AB-Test226-8037affd-06d1-4c61-a91f-816ec9cb825f-05202017-4.tar,
esarchive--Jackson-HQ-112-ecb5ab6a-c199-402d-9a8a-8c54c8901d66-06012017-4.tar,
esarchive--Jonah-7fbbbc6c-8463-4ec1-9bde-3fc5429311e5-06092017-4
```

How do I extract the latest .tar file name for each customer, such as Mona, Jackson, Jonah mentioned in their respective filename as per their date values (At the end in the File Name) so that I get a variable with values:

```
esarchive--Mona-AB-Test226-8037affd-06d1-4c61-a91f-816ec9cb825f-05222017-4.tar,
esarchive--Jackson-HQ-112-ecb5ab6a-c199-402d-9a8a-8c54c8901d66-06092017-4.tar,
esarchive--Jonah-7fbbbc6c-8463-4ec1-9bde-3fc5429311e5-06092017-4
```

I have executed the following code so far:-

```
    for file in glob.glob("*.tar"):
   # print "The File Being Untarred is:",file
    file_date_str = file.split('-')[-2]
    datetime_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(file_date_str, '%m%d%Y')
    a=re.match("esarchive--(\w+)-(\w+)-(\w+)", file).group(1)# Gets Mona from file name
    b=re.match("esarchive--(\w+)-(\w+)-(\w+)", file).group(2)# Gets AB from file name
    c=re.match("esarchive--(\w+)-(\w+)-(\w+)", file).group(3)# Gets Test226 from file name
    s = a+'-'+b+'-'+c
    d=s.lower()
    my_dict={}
    date = datetime.date.today()
    print(s)
    try:
        (latest_date, _) = my_dict['name'] # _ has file name, which you don't want to compare.
        if date > latest_date:
        # If entry for this name exists,
        # Replace the info with latest date.
           my_dict['name'] = (date,file)
    except KeyError:
    # No info for this name in dictionary.
           my_dict['name'] = (date,file)

    print "The File Being Untarred is:",my_dict['name']
    tar = tarfile.open("/home/chetan/Desktop/supertar/"+my_dict['name'][1]) 
    tar.extractall(path="/home/chetan/Documents/chetan-dump-es") # untar file into same directory
    tar.close()
```

I am getting a list of all files instead of only the latest ones.

Comment: You don't want to be updating the same dict key 'name' each time, you'll probably want something more along the lines of `my_dict[filename] = date`

Comment: As the error indicates, `date` is not defined. I supposed you wanted to use `d` instead of `date`: `my_dict['name'] = (d, file_name)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought your data looks familiar... Didn't we already cover that on your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44271354/7553525)? With minor tweaks the previous answer can be adapted to this case - you just don't need a list of all the files and only need the top values for each 'customer', and you can extract a 'customer' as you can extract the same way as the date (which you don't need to fully parse at all, as shown in my previous answer).

Something like:

```
def parse_date(name, offset=-10):  # lets re-use our convenience function
    try:
        date_str = name[offset:offset+8]
        return int(date_str[-4:] + date_str[:2] + date_str[2:4])
    except (IndexError, TypeError, ValueError):  # invalid file name
        return -1

result = {}  # use this as our result / lookup table
for file_name in glob.glob("*.tar"):
    # for customer name, skip `esarchive--` and pick everything until the next dash
    customer = file_name[11:file_name.find("-", 11)]
    date = parse_date(file_name, -14)
    # now replace our stored value if it's older than the date in our current file name
    if result.get(customer, [-1])[0] < date:
        result[customer] = [date, file_name]  # store the parsed date and file name
```

Then you can consume it (assuming your posted data) as:

```
for k, v in result.items():
    print("Customer: {}\n\tDate: {}\n\tFile: {}".format(k, v[0], v[1]))
# prints:
# Customer: Jonah
#   Date: 20170609
#   File: esarchive--Jonah-7fbbbc6c-8463-4ec1-9bde-3fc5429311e5-06092017-4.tar
# Customer: Jackson
#   Date: 20170609
#   File: esarchive--Jackson-HQ-112-ecb5ab6a-c199-402d-9a8a-8c54c8901d66-06092017-4.tar
# Customer: Mona
#   Date: 20170522
#   File: esarchive--Mona-AB-Test226-8037affd-06d1-4c61-a91f-816ec9cb825f-05222017-4.tar

# or if you just want the list of file names:
file_names = [entry[1] for entry in result.values()]
# ['esarchive--Jonah-7fbbbc6c-8463-4ec1-9bde-3fc5429311e5-06092017-4.tar',
#  'esarchive--Jackson-HQ-112-ecb5ab6a-c199-402d-9a8a-8c54c8901d66-06092017-4.tar',
#  'esarchive--Mona-AB-Test226-8037affd-06d1-4c61-a91f-816ec9cb825f-05222017-4.tar']
```